# How do you resolve an MVC namespace compile error after renaming model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first

I have an model I reference in a DbContext class I'm using to generate my code-first DB. Originally the model was named FeedEventDomainModel and I changed the name to FeedEventCommand.I haven't generated the DB yet; however when I run the application to open Index.html under the areas folder, I receive the following error:

[image]

Code:

 
**DbContext Class**

```
using System.Data.Entity;
namespace OProj.DataContext
{
    public class OProjDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public OProjDBContext() : base("name=OProjDB")
        {
        }

        public DbSet<FeedEventCommand> FeedEvents { get; set; }

    }
}
```

**FeedEventCommand**

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace OProj.DataContext
{
    public class FeedEventCommand
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int AnimalId { get; set; }

        public int FeederTypeId { get; set; }

        public string FeederType { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My question is since I changed the name of my model from FeedEventDomainModel to FeedEventCommand, is there a place in cache I need to clear so it doesn't keep referencing the old model name?

Answer (score 0):

1. do a full clean.
2. close Visual Studio
3. delete the temp files in Windows/Microsoft.Net/Framework and Framework64/v4.0/Temporary ASP.NET Files
4. reopen the solution in VS, rebuild and it should work.

renaming things has that kind of effect so you have to delete the cached files

Comment: I'm not finding a Temporary Internet Files folder under either Framework Folder

Comment: updated the answer with the correct path. I missed the framework version number

Comment: Checked those folders. No temp files. Cleaned, rebuilt project and relaunched it. Issue persists